# Filter DataSet for relational data

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have few tables in the database with parent table say P is having 1:1 relation with some child tables whereas having 1:M relation with other child tables.

For this I have added DataSet at design time by 'Add -> New Item -> DataSet -> DataSet1.xsd'
So, I have all the required tables along with their 1:1 or 1:M relations.

I have applied some filter on main table adapter so that only selected records from parent table and their related child records are populated in the dataset. And finally, I want to write this data from DataSet to Xml file.

But, I am getting one issue - the final dataset that I am getting is having all the records from child table. Instead it should have only those child records for which parent table is having related records.

I am using following code -

```
ParentDataSet parentDataSet = new ParentDataSet();
 ParentTableAdapter parentTableAdapter = new ParentTableAdapter();
 parentTableAdapter.Fill(parentDataSet.ParentTable, column1Value); // All fine until here as I have applied filter in tableAdapter SQL

 ChildTableAdapter childTableAdapter = new ChildTableAdapter();
 //returns all rows in the child table -- shouldn't it return only those child records for which parent dataset table is having records??
 childTableAdapter.Fill(parentDataSet.ChildTable);  

 parentDataSet.WriteXml(xmlFilePath);
```

Please guide what I am missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/07/10/working-with-tableadapters-related-datatables-and-transactions.aspx)?  The author says that

> By default, the `DataSet` designer sets the `DataRelations` between
>   parent-child tables as **"Relation Only"**. This means that the `DataSet`
>   will not enforce the foreign key constraints on the client, just your
>   database...

Try changing the type of the parent-child relation to a foreign key constraint. Then, check the `SelectCommand` property of the `ChildTableAdapter`. It is filtering the data the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It didn't solve the issue - So it seems I have to add filter for related tables as well as I have added for parent table.

Comment: I ended up adding filter for parent as well as related child tables :-)

Comment: @iniki Since my answer doesn't actually solve the problem, you should post your solution as a separate answer and accept it.  (You can accept your own answer to a question that you asked.)